# Elisp List Contains a Value

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do you check, in elisp, if a list contains a value?  so the following would return t:

```
(contains 3 '(1 2 3))
```

but

```
(contains 5 '(1 2 3))
```

would return nil.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The function you need is `member`

For example:

```
(member 3 '(1 2 3))
```

It will return the tail of *list* whose car is *element*.  While this is not strictly `t`, [any non-nil value is equivalent to true for a boolean operation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/nil-and-t.html#nil-and-t).  Also, [`member` uses `equal`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html) to test for equality, use `memq` for stricter equality (using `eq`).

Comment: For further details, see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/List-Processing.html

Answer (score 8):

[freiksenet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408990/596361) is good and idiomatic. If you are using [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), you could also call function [`-contains?`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-contains-list-element), which does exactly the same—checks if some list contains an element:

```
(-contains? '(1 2 3) 2) ; t
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to find an element by applying a function, [there's a `seq-find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#index-seq_002dfind):

```lisp
(seq-find (lambda (val) (= 3 val))
          '(1 2 3))
```