# Emacs Auto Load Color Theme by Time

Tags: emacs, elisp

Can I let Emacs automatically load theme ? or do certain command at customized time ? Say what I want is to `M-x load-theme RET solarized-light` when I am at office at 9:00am and `M-x laod-theme RET solarized-dark` when I am back home and continued on emacs at 8:00pm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To expand on @Anton Kovalenko's answer, you can get the current time using the [current-time-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html) elisp function and extracting the current time of day in hours.

If you want to write a full implementation, you could do something like (**Warning, not debugged**):

```
;; <Color theme initialization code>
(setq current-theme '(color-theme-solarized-light))

(defun synchronize-theme ()
    (setq hour 
        (string-to-number 
            (substring (current-time-string) 11 13)))
    (if (member hour (number-sequence 6 17))
        (setq now '(color-theme-solarized-light))
        (setq now '(color-theme-solarized-dark))) 
    (if (equal now current-theme)
        nil
        (setq current-theme now)
        (eval now) ) ) ;; end of (defun ...

(run-with-timer 0 3600 synchronize-theme)
```

For more info on the functions used, see the following sections of the emacs manual:

- [Time of day](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-of-Day.html)
- [Strings](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_71.html)
- [String Conversions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/String-Conversion.html)
- [Idle Timers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html)
- [Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408974/789750)
- [Number Sequence](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#Building-Lists)

Comment: Great example. I use emacs daily but never tried to learn elisp. Just started learning and following your example. It works. Thanks. Small reminder: should that be `substring (current-time-string) 11 13)` ? no parentheses? also it turns out adding a `'` before `synchronize-theme` in `run-with-timer` works.

Comment: @liuminzhao: Could you clarify what needs to be fixed (or fix it yourself directly).

Comment: It works after some bug fix: (if (eq now current-theme)  to (if (equal now current-theme)

Comment: @tangxinfa: feel free to edit the answer to fix the bug.

Answer (score 12):

Another (very elegant) solution is *theme-changer*.

Given a location and day/night color themes, this file provides a change-theme function that selects the appropriate theme based on whether it is day or night. It will continue to change themes at sunrise and sunset. To install:

Set the location:

```
(setq calendar-location-name "Dallas, TX") 
(setq calendar-latitude 32.85)
(setq calendar-longitude -96.85)
```

Specify the day and night themes:

```
(require 'theme-changer)
(change-theme 'tango 'tango-dark)
```

The project is hosted [on Github](https://github.com/hadronzoo/theme-changer), and can be installed through melpa.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this snippet of code to do what you want.

```
(defvar install-theme-loading-times nil
  "An association list of time strings and theme names.
The themes will be loaded at the specified time every day.")
(defvar install-theme-timers nil)
(defun install-theme-loading-at-times ()
  "Set up theme loading according to `install-theme-loading-at-times`"
  (interactive)
  (dolist (timer install-theme-timers)
(cancel-timer timer))
  (setq install-theme-timers nil)
  (dolist (time-theme install-theme-loading-times)
(add-to-list 'install-theme-timers
         (run-at-time (car time-theme) (* 60 60 24) 'load-theme (cdr time-theme)))))
```

Just customize the variable `install-theme-loading-times` as desired:

```
(setq install-theme-loading-times '(("9:00am" . solarized-light)
                ("8:00pm" . solarized-dark)))
```

Comment: Followed @Dan 's code it works. And I will learn elisp by your code too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with `run-with-timer` function:

```
(run-with-timer SECS REPEAT FUNCTION &rest ARGS)

Perform an action after a delay of SECS seconds.
Repeat the action every REPEAT seconds, if REPEAT is non-nil.
SECS and REPEAT may be integers or floating point numbers.
The action is to call FUNCTION with arguments ARGS.

This function returns a timer object which you can use in `cancel-timer'.
```

Schedule a function to run every minute or so, which will check
current time and call `load-theme` when appropriate (don't switch
theme every minute, even if it's reloading the current theme).

Comment: Thanks for direction. Following @Dan code, I think I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found this simple code that works for doom emacs. Put this in the config file:

```
(load-theme 'solarized-light t t) ;;load light theme
(run-at-time "09:00" (* 60 60 24) (lambda () (enable-theme 'solarized-light)))
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t t) ;;load dark theme
(run-at-time "20:00" (* 60 60 24) (lambda () (enable-theme 'solarized-dark)))
```

replace light and dark themes with your choice. time can also be changed from 9am/8pm in 24-hour format.

source and credit: https://parasurv.neocities.org/emacs/change-emacs-theme-depending-on-time.html

Answer (score 1):

This implementation changes theme based on sunrise and sunset times of the latitude and longitude you provide. The only dependency is `solar.el` which is released with Emacs (IIRC).

(I think the code can probably be shorter here.)

```
;; theme changing at sunrises and sunsets according to lat and long
(require 'solar)

(defun today-date-integer (offset)
  "Returns today's date in a list of integers, i.e. month, date, and year, in system time."
  (let* ((date (mapcar
   (lambda (pattern)
     (string-to-number (format-time-string pattern)))
   '("%m" "%d" "%Y"))))
    (setcar
   (nthcdr
    1
    date)
   (+ offset (nth 1 date)))
    date))

(defun current-time-decimal ()
  (let* ((current-min-fraction (/ (string-to-number (format-time-string "%M")) 60.0))
    (current-hour (string-to-number (format-time-string "%H"))))
    (+ current-hour current-min-fraction)))

(defun next-alarm-time (sunrise-time sunset-time)
  (let* ((current-time (current-time-decimal)))
   (cond ((< current-time sunrise-time)
       (- sunrise-time current-time))
    ((and (>= current-time sunrise-time)
          (< current-time sunset-time))
      (- sunset-time current-time))
    ((>= current-time sunset-time)
     (let ((tomorrow-sunrise-time (car (car (solar-sunrise-sunset (today-date-integer 1))))))
       (- (+ 24 tomorrow-sunrise-time) current-time))))))

(defun to-seconds (hour) (* hour 60 60))

(defun change-theme (light-theme dark-theme coor)
  (let* ((_ (setq calendar-latitude (car coor)))
    ( _ (setq calendar-longitude (nth 1 coor)))
    (today-date (today-date-integer 0))
    (sunrise-sunset-list (solar-sunrise-sunset today-date))
    (sunrise-time (car (car sunrise-sunset-list)))
    (sunset-time (car (nth 1 sunrise-sunset-list)))
    (current-time (current-time-decimal))
    (current-theme (if (or (< current-time sunrise-time) (> current-time sunset-time))
             dark-theme
             light-theme))
    (next-alarm-t (next-alarm-time sunrise-time sunset-time)))
    (cancel-function-timers 'change-theme)
    (load-theme current-theme t)
    (run-at-time
     (to-seconds next-alarm-t) nil 'change-theme light-theme dark-theme coor)))

(change-theme 'solarized-gruvbox-light 'solarized-gruvbox-dark '(47.6062 -122.3321))
```